# QueryInterface fails on Windows Vista

Tags: com, windows-vista, atl

Having a simple out of process COM server, instantiating with the interface or querying the interface from it's `IUnknown` works on <strike>Windows 7 and up</strike> some machines but fails on <strike>Windows Vista</strike> others with `E_NOINTERFACE`.

I have the feeling it has to do something with marshaling because I'm seeing the QI succeed on the server side.

The interface is very simple, I only changed some names:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(3FEE2913-52C7-46DB-B5AA-298263FB5393),
    oleautomation,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("My ISuperDuper Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ISuperDuper : IUnknown {
    HRESULT get_Version([out, retval]BSTR* version_string);
};
```

The exe server is implemented with ATL:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CSuperDuper : 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CSuperDuper, &CLSID_SuperDuper>,
    public ISuperDuper
{
public:
    CSuperDuper(){}

    DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_SUPERDUPER)
    DECLARE_NOT_AGGREGATABLE(CSuperDuper)

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CSuperDuper)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISuperDuper)
    END_COM_MAP()

    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct() {
        return WaitForServerStart() ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
    }

public:
    STDMETHOD(get_Version)(BSTR *version_string) {
        CComBSTR version(_T(VERSION_NUMBER_STR_DOT));
        return version.CopyTo(version_string);
    }
};
```

The client code tries to instantiate the server but fails with `E_NOINTERFACE`:

```
bool StartServer() {
    ComInit com(COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if(SUCCEEDED(com.result) || com.result == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE) {
        CComPtr<ISuperDuper> server;
        auto result = server.CoCreateInstance(L"CompanyName.SuperDuper");
        LOG_DBG("CoCreateInstance result: " << std::hex << result);

        if(server!= nullptr) {
            CComBSTR version;
            if(SUCCEEDED(server->get_Version(&version)) && version.m_str) {
                LOG_DBG("Started server version " << version.m_str);
            } else {
                LOG_WRN("Failed to get version from server");
            }
        } else {
            LOG_ERR("Failed to start Server");
        }

        return server != nullptr;
    } else {
        LOG_ERR("Failed to initialize COM: " << std::hex << com.result);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This version successfully creates an `IUnknown` first but then fails to QI:

```
CComPtr<IUnknown> server;
auto result = server.CoCreateInstance(L"CompanyName.SuperDuper");

if(server!= nullptr) {
    CComQIPtr<IDeviceMonitor> server_if = server;
    if(server_if) {
        CComBSTR version;
        if(SUCCEEDED(server_if->get_Version(&version)) && version.m_str) {
            LOG_DBG("Started COM server version " << version.m_str);
        } // ...
    } else {
        LOG_WRN("Failed to QI server");
    }
}
```

Please note again that **this works fine on <strike>Windows 7 and up</strike> some machines**. There is something that fails on <strike>Windows Vista</strike> some machines between the server returning it's `ISuperDuper` and it arriving in the other process.

**Edit:** I got some QA reports that something similar has been seen on machines other than Visa, so I'm not sure this is related to Vista only. I can reproduce this on a Vista machine.

I'm stuck. Any ideas?

**Edit 2:**
Assuming it's a marshalling problem, how would you debug the issue to find the reason and come up with a solution?

**Edit 3:**
The intallation of the server is per user. The typelib is linked in the exe, we use the standard ATL exe server registration to do the work. It registers the following:

- Registers the App in `HKCR\AppId\...`
- Registers the server in `HKCR\MyCompany.SuperDuper` to its CLSID.
- Registers the CLSID in `HKCR\CLSID\<CLSID>` and points it to the EXE and the Typelib. Typelib is registerd with it's LIBID.
- Registers the interface in `HKCR\Interface\<IID>` and connects it to the typelib with the LIBID.
- Registers the typelib in `HKCR\Typelib\<LIBID>`. Points to the correct exe.

I double checked that these entries exist on the affected machine and it's failing. I also checked that the type library is actually in the exe.

Comment: This code is completely incapable of giving you a diagnostic of the problem.  It uses "it didn't work" error logging.  You have no idea if it *actually* failed on E_NOINTERFACE.  Logging the HRESULT is not optional.

Comment: Most likely, on those machines that exhibit the problem, the type library describing your interface is not registered. It needs to be, in order to support marshaling.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I cut the line logging the `result` because of the conversion library I use for that line. I logged the result and I see it in the debugger. I also stepped through pretty much all of the code posted including the `QueryInterface` method hid behind the `COM_MAP` macros. I'm adding a line representing that above.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I use `oleautomation` in the interface and keep it simple so that I don't need a custom marshaller. My understanding is that a limited set of types (including `BSTR`) are supported by default.

Comment: When you want to use a custom marshaller, you need to built and register a proxy/stub DLL. When, as here, you want to use universal marshaller, you need to build and register a type library. Without either, how exactly do you expect the system to know that your interface is marked `[oleautomation]` and your method takes a `BSTR`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik IIRC The type library is linked in the exe. Please don't forget, this works fine on most systems, it just seems to fail on some (mostly or all Vista). That said the problem *is* probably somewhere with the marshalling.

Comment: It doesn't matter how the type library is deployed, be it as a standalone file or bound as a resource to some binary. It still needs to be registered. On the system that works, check `HKCR\Interface\{3FEE2913-52C7-46DB-B5AA-298263FB5393}` key - it should have a subkey named `TypeLib` whose default value is a `LIBID` of the type library. Further, there should be `HKCR\TypeLib\{LIBID}` key (for that particular LIBID), with a few obvious subkeys that eventually point to the place where the type library is physically located.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik please see update. It seems like everything is where it should be, unless there are some peculiarities with Vista.